# Delete lines from multiple textfiles in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, text-files, powershell-2.0

I am trying to delete lines with a defined content from multiple textfiles.

It works in the core, but it will rewrite every file even if no changes are made, which is not cool if you are just modifying 50 out of about 3000 logonscripts.
I even made a if statement but it seems like it doesn't work.

Alright this is what I already have:

```
#Here $varFind will be escaped from potential RegEx triggers.
$varFindEscaped = [regex]::Escape($varFind)

#Here the deletion happens.
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $varPath*$varEnding) {
    $contentBefore = Get-Content $file
    $contentAfter = Get-Content $file | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $varFindEscaped}
    if ($contentBefore -ne $contentAfter) {Set-Content $file $contentAfter}
}
```

What the variables mean:
**$varPath** is the path in which the logonscripts are.
**$varEnding** is the file ending of the files to modify.
**$varFind** is the string that triggers the deletion of the line.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Greetings
Löwä Cent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the file regardless but some improvement on your change condition could help.

```
#Here the deletion happens.
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $varPath*$varEnding) {
    $data = (Get-Content $file)
    If($data -match $varFindEscaped){
        $data | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $varFindEscaped} | Set-Content $file
    }
}
```

Read the file into `$data`. Check to see if the pattern `$varFindEscaped` is present in the file. If it is than filter out those matching the same pattern. Else we move onto the next file.

Comment: Hi Matt your code works like a charm! Thank you very much!